# Split String into Parts PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

Have the following string i need to split.

```
$string = "This is string sample - $2565";
$split_point = " - ";
```

One:
I need to be able to split the string into two parts using a regex or any other match and specify where is going to split.

Second:
Also want to do a preg_match for $ and then only grab number on the right of $.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It is hard to know how your input strings may vary when you only supply one sample string.  Do you expect `This is string sample` and `2565` as the two elements in the output array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$split_string = explode($split_point, $string);
```

and

```
preg_match('/\$(\d*)/', $split_string[1], $matches);
$amount = $matches[1];
```

If you want, this could all be done in one regex with:

```
$pattern = '/^(.*)'.preg_quote($split_point).'\$(\d*)$/'

preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
$description = $matches[1];
$amount = $matches[2];
```

Comment: Please, to avoid unexpected errors, do add preg_quote around the $split_point in the regex example.

Answer (score 1):

```
$parts = explode ($split_point, $string);
/*
$parts[0] = 'This is string sample'
$parts[1] = '$2565'
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Two other answers have mentioned `explode()`, but you can also limit the number of parts it's meant to split your source string into. For instance:

```
$s = "This is - my - string.";
list($head, $tail) = explode(' - ', $s, 2);
echo "Head is '$head' and tail is '$tail'\n";
```

Will given you:

```
Head is 'This is' and tail is 'my - string.'
```

Comment: Isn't the output: Head is 'This is-' and tail is 'my - string.' ?

Comment: Nope, definitely not. I even checked it in the PHP REPL before posting.

Comment: so what happened to the first - ?

Comment: your completely right. I forgot you exploded " - " and not "-".

Comment: how will i split from the last - and not the first. can i make explode search from right to left instead?

Comment: There's no simple way to do that, mainly because it's not something you usually want to do. Unfortunately, the intuitive way of doing it (using a negative number) does something completely different. Try exploding the string, popping the last element, and imploding it again.

Answer (score 0):

`explode` is the right solution for your specific case, but `preg_split` is what you want if you ever need regular expressions for the separator